# Transfer Google Apps Domain to Godaddy?

Tags: g-suite, godaddy

I have a domain name I registered with Google Apps.  Great - it's nice that it comes with all of the cool Googly services.  However, I now wish to transfer it to someone else, who has an account with GoDaddy.  Anyone have any tips about doing this?

Incidentally, I'm not sure serverfault is the right place for this question - I'll happily ask it elsewhere if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Google is your registrar at the moment?  I didn't know they did that.  In any case, domain name transfers are usually pretty simple and typically involve initiating a transfer request with the new registrar.  This process is covered in the GoDaddy help center: http://help.godaddy.com/article/1592

Comment: Google isn't actually the registrar, but it's all a bit confused because of how things work.  For some reason, GoDaddy simply can't handle the transfer, so my counterparty has been utilizing name.com, where things are working better.